# The driver for my Visioneer One Touch 6600USB will not install

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, scanner

I have followed all instructions thrice carefully. When I try to install the driver, I get a message that the install failed as the driver is for the One Touch 6600 only. The scanner is not attached to the computer at this time, and I have followed all uninstall instructions.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

XP Pro, SP3.

EDIT: I found the problem, there was a program I had missed. All okay now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you disable antivirus? There are virus patterns in the installation software.

Did you uninstall all previous software and drivers, and reboot, before trying again? (Try running [Infclear](http://support.visioneer.com/products/Tools/Utilities_2000_XP.asp) to get rid of any remnants of the driver.)

Are you using the most recent version of the driver from the website (software and drivers that comes with hardware on CD's is often first edition and buggy)?

Comment: 1. I did disable anti-virus. 2. I DID NOT re-boot. 3. I am running the softward from the site. I will try again, thanks.

Comment: I have other scanner software on my computer, namely Paperport. Do I need to uninstall it as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use the registry to uninstall manually. Here are the steps:

- Open regedit
- Find the CLSID key for Scanners
- Remove it {E211B736-43FD-11D1-9EFB-0000F8757FCD}
- Find the CLSID key for Portable Media Devices
- Remove it {640167b4-59b0-47a6-b335-a6b3c0695aea}
- Download {905667aa-acd6-11d2-8080-00805f6596d2} wiashext.dll from dlldump
- Download {D1621129-45C4-41AD-A1D1-AF7EAFABEEDC} wiadefui.dll from dlldump
- Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Current Control Set\Enum\Usb
- Right-click the USB key, and then click Permissions.
- In the Group or Users Name section, click EVERYONE
- In the Everyone permissions section, select the check box in the Allow column check box for Everyone.
- If the key VID_0000&PID_0000 is present, right-click it and then click Delete.
- Delete All PID_ entries for uninstalled hardware
- Delete all Microsoft*\Installer keys

**References**

- [I cannot delete, move, or rename a file on my PC](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/viruses-spyware-and-other-nasties/threads/27783/i-cannot-delete-move-or-rename-a-file-on-my-pc)
- [CLSID List](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/CLSID-List.htm)